# Represented by 2 agencies(head hunters) at the same company

Tags: recruitment

I applied position A at the company  last October through the Headhunter.
I did't get that job and I wasn't satisfied to work with the headhunter.Frankly
I was very upset that the headhunter didn't reply back to my email and found out 
he did't pass the documents that I wanted to deliver to the Hiring manager.

About a month later, I contacted by the other headhunter from other agency.
The position was for the same company that I've applied for a  month ago,
(the position was in different department). I told the headhunter about the situation , at first she said that I might not be able to apply for that position.

the day after , she called me that she talked about me to the HR at the company and HR  wanted to meet me. I asked the headhunter I already met the HR at the company. but the headhunter told HR team is totally divided by department so 
it will be fine at that stage.

After several interview, I got final interview and went well, I am very positive getting this job.

Today, the recruiter called me and she will not be able to handle my process anymore since I represented by other headhunter before. (Also the HR who was working for this position has quit, so their HR team was restructured and HR who I met for the first position will be handling my process)

I like the 2nd headhunter,(I know seems she shouldn't proceed process with me), I felt she was very helpful.

the head hunter said if I want to keep process with her , email direct to the HR
and state that I want to work with her instead of first agency.

My concerns are:

1)It would be ok to ask HR? I'd love to give the credit to my 2nd headhunter 
but I don't  know well about headhunting industry and don't want to create the complicated situation (+ legal issue probably) to effect their hiring decision.

2)I haven't got any official offer and only have a good feeling,
so I'm not sure if it's appropriate timing to the email HR.

Comment: Whithout knowing the country you are at, it is impossible to answer properly. Please add a country tag.

Comment: What is your standing with the first headhunter? Did you have an exclusive agreement with that guy (probably not)?

Answer (score 1):

The first headhunter's lead was finished when you applied and didn't get the job. The second headhunter had a second lead, which applies to your current job application. I don't understand why there would be any situation to resolve. This would be like saying "Realtor X tried to get me a house and said I couldn't, but Realtor Y sold me the house...so all the money should go to Realtor X because they tried first" or any other sales situation. Headhunters are selling you to a company. This one did, the other one didn't.

That said, I would for sure find out whether there was a "sale" or not. If you don't work there, talking to HR is a somewhat bad idea. If you DO get the job, you'll have to sign paperwork. During that process I would talk to the HR head to explain the situation and, again, let them know that the "selling agent" should get the credit.